# Usage of the phrase 'To be a long time in doing something'

Tags: phrase-usage, usage

Usage of the phrase 'To be a long time in doing something'.

I'm reading Orwell's *Animal Farm*. Chapter 9 begins with this sentence:

> Boxer's split hoof was a long time in healing.

Does this mean that Boxer's split hoof ***took*** a long time to heal?

I'd like to know the grammar behind this usage. How can someone *be a time*--since this is what the sentence literally says?

I presume it is idiomatic because I tried running a serach with 'was a short time in...' but I got no results.

I couldn't find any definition in dictionaries, though.

Another explanation could be that Boxer's hoof was a long time in healing, meaning in the state/process of healing, so healing is a noun.

Comment: Your first interpretation is correct.  You're also right about this being idiomatic - for some reason we say "X was a long time in *verbing*" a lot more than we say "was a *short* time in *verbing*"!

Comment: @stangdon - I am familiar with to _lose no time in_ something, e.g. neighbours lost no time in rushing to help when a grandmother's house caught fire

Answer (score 1):

Yes, *[ be-verb + "a long time in" + X + "ing" ]* is an idiomatic structure with the same function as, "*X-ing took a long time*". There is no idiomatic equivalent with "short" meaning something happened quickly, though if you said, "Boxer's hoof was a short time in healing," it would be easily understood.